# How to run local exe file from web application in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed a web application that runs an exe file.

It working fine in my local machine.

When I host the application in the server, the exe file is not executing.

I am using following code to run the exe file.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\Debug\VncSharpExampleCS.exe";
        p.Start();
```

Can anybody please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of web application running on that server. Make sure you are using the correct exe path on that server.

Comment: Maybe the user behind the web server doesn't have permission to access this location...

Comment: How to give permission to server to access our local pc path to run exe. @Taysumi

Comment: I am using MVC application from this I want to call winform exe file which is on client machine. @Ganeshkumar

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. Please update

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"Data\myApp.exe");
int id = process.Id;
Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
this.Visible = false;
tempProc.WaitForExit();
this.Visible = true;
```

Furthermore, you can get more information from this [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: My exe is on client machine, not on server. then how my application call that local exe?